# How to append a child as second last. (Just before last)

Tags: jquery

I have an application, Just you can imagine as Facebook comment system, where post, Comments for that post, and new Text area for post your comment is available.

Example -

```
post1.. All comments for that post.. text area for new comment
post2.. All comments for that post.. text area for new comment
post3.. All comments for that post.. text area for new comment
```

.
.

My problem is while i post a new comments its get appended after the text area. I want to post the comment at just before text area, along with all comments. How should i use the JQuery append method to achieve this functionality.

Thanks in advance. Sapna

You can refer this url.. http://wowopage.in/cgi-bin/requests.pl
Try to response to any requests you will get the exact problem.
To provide response you must be logged-in. Please use my credentials. 
sapnakool4u@gmail.com and passs-  sapna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the `textarea` and use [jQuery before](http://api.jquery.com/before/). E.g.:

```
$('#post1 textarea').before(stringWithNewComments);
```

(Because you haven't post your whole html the selector is only an example and you have to update it.)

Comment: Hi scessor, I think this will work. But problem is div ID i am calculating on the fly.                                               $("#"+getpID ).append(htmlcode).fadeIn();   Can you please help me adding textarea here.

Answer (score 0):

you have not provided any markup so its very hard to guess ... anyhow you can use

```
.before
```

to append what ever before the textarea

http://api.jquery.com/before/

Comment: I used **before** as well, Its appending as a very first child.

Comment: are you appending the comments as `li` ?